# OpenSSl 3 not verifying (using) tag using chacha20 poly1305

Tags: c++, c, encryption, openssl, cryptography

i just started learning openssl,
when i use chacha20_poly1305() to encrypt and mac some text, it does not work
What am i doing wrong, how does this work

```cpp
int main( )
{
    unsigned char key[] = "01234567890123456789012345678912";
    unsigned char iv[]  = "0123456789012345";

    unsigned char pt[23] = "plaintext of length 23";
    unsigned char ct[23 + 16];
    unsigned char dt[23];

    memset( ct, '\0', sizeof( ct ) );
    memset( dt, '\0', sizeof( dt ) );

    int ct_bw{ 0 };
    int dt_bw{ 0 };
    int status{ -19 };
    {
        // Encrypt
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ectx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
        EVP_EncryptInit_ex2( ectx, EVP_chacha20_poly1305(), key, iv,
                                         nullptr );

        EVP_EncryptUpdate( ectx, ct, &ct_bw, pt, 23 );

        int bw = ct_bw;

        EVP_EncryptFinal_ex( ectx, ct + ct_bw, &ct_bw );
        ct_bw += bw;

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free( ectx );
        for(int i=24;i<34;i++){
            //tag id not stored at the end of the ciphertext!!!
            ct[i]='\0';
        }

    }
    {
        // Decrypt
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX* dctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
        EVP_DecryptInit_ex( dctx, EVP_chacha20_poly1305(), nullptr,
                                        key, iv );

        EVP_DecryptUpdate( dctx, dt, &dt_bw, ct, ct_bw );

        status = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex( dctx, dt + dt_bw, &dt_bw );

        //decrypts sucsessfully, with sucsess status code of 1
        //https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/EVP_EncryptInit.html in return values
        //does not verify tag, or write it anywhere
        printf("\nstatus:%i decrypted_test:%s\n",status,dt);

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free( dctx );
    }

}
```

ps: EVP_chacha20 and EVP_chacha20_poly1305() dont work interopratably..(as they shouldnt).

Answer (score 0):

From the [EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl.html) docs:

> *ChaCha20-Poly1305*
>
> The following ctrls are supported for the ChaCha20-Poly1305 AEAD
> algorithm.
>
> EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_AEAD_SET_IVLEN, ivlen, NULL)
>
> Sets the nonce length. This call can only be made before specifying the nonce. If not called a default nonce length of 12 (i.e.
> 96 bits) is used. The maximum nonce length is 12 bytes (i.e. 96-bits).
> If a nonce of less than 12 bytes is set then the nonce is
> automatically padded with leading 0 bytes to make it 12 bytes in
> length. EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_AEAD_GET_TAG, taglen, tag)
>
> Writes taglen bytes of the tag value to the buffer indicated by tag. This call can only be made when encrypting data and after all
> data has been processed (e.g. after an EVP_EncryptFinal() call).
>
> taglen specified here must be 16 (POLY1305_BLOCK_SIZE, i.e. 128-bits) or less. EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_AEAD_SET_TAG,
> taglen, tag)
>
> Sets the expected tag to taglen bytes from tag. The tag length can only be set before specifying an IV. taglen must be between 1 and 16
> (POLY1305_BLOCK_SIZE) inclusive. This call is only valid when
> decrypting data.

So for your example you need to change to do:

```
{
    // Encrypt
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ectx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex2( ectx, EVP_chacha20_poly1305(), key, iv,
                                     nullptr );

    EVP_EncryptUpdate( ectx, ct, &ct_bw, pt, 23 );

    int bw = ct_bw;

    EVP_EncryptFinal_ex( ectx, ct + ct_bw, &ct_bw );
    ct_bw += bw;

    assert(ct_bw <= 23);

    // get tag
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ectx, EVP_CTRL_AEAD_GET_TAG, 16, ct + ct_bw);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free( ectx );
}
{
    // Decrypt
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* dctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_DecryptInit_ex( dctx, EVP_chacha20_poly1305(), nullptr,
                                    key, iv );

    // set tag
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(dctx, EVP_CTRL_AEAD_SET_TAG, 16, ct + ct_bw);

    EVP_DecryptUpdate( dctx, dt, &dt_bw, ct, ct_bw );

    status = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex( dctx, dt + dt_bw, &dt_bw );

    //decrypts successfully, with success status code of 1
    //https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/EVP_EncryptInit.html in return values
    printf("\nstatus:%i decrypted_test:%s\n",status,dt);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free( dctx );
}
```

Comment: i figured that out some time later... but...the problem is  if i remove ``` // set tag
    //EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(dctx, EVP_CTRL_AEAD_SET_TAG, 16, ct + ct_bw);   ``` it still works (return code is sucsess), it shouldnt.. the mode is set to an authnticated encryption mode and if the tag is misssing (not specified) it should fail...

Comment: Setting the tag means that it will tell you if the decrypt fails (i.e. the dencypted data is bad).  e.g. if you memset ct to all zeros for ct_bw length, without the tag set the decyprt will be succesfully but the output will be bad.  With the tag set the decrypt will fail.